# interpolating polymorphic relation type in url paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, paperclip

I have a photo model which is polymorphic

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
 has_attached_file :image,
                :styles => {:thumb => '120x120>', :medium => '640x480>' },
                :default_style => :thumb,
                :url => "/uploads/photos/#{model.imageable_type.to_s.pluralize.underscore}/:id/:basename.:extension"
```

and

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :photo, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy


class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :photo, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
```

this generates the url as uploads/photos/Photo/some_id/file_name.ext
but I want

```
public/uploads/photos/questions/1/image.jpg
```

and

```
public/uploads/photos/answers/1/image.jpg.
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself.

```
   :url => "/uploads/photos/:imageable_name/:id/:basename.:extension"


Paperclip.interpolates :imageable_name  do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.imageable_type.pluralize.downcase
end
```